# informal word for a money manager

Tags: idioms, nouns, american-english

Imagine there's a group of friends and they're on a trip or on vacation. They're not going to chip in for every single spending; instead, a certain person shells out for everything throughout and when they're back home (back from trip) THAT certain person figures each person's share of expenses and then charge them.

The question is what THAT person is called? I mean if there's any idiom or informal word for it.

Comment: A "normal" person (concerned about their money and expenses) ?

Comment: Say, we're 5 people and decide to go to Paris. In there I pay for meals, museums tickets, transfers. But when we get back home, I split the amount of money I spent in there by 5. Is banker or treasurer on the right money?

Answer (score 1):

That person would normally be referred to as the treasurer or, at least on some golf trips I've been on, the purser.

Answer (score 1):

That person is informally called the *banker*.

As with a credit card or a bank loan, they pay first, and you pay them back later.